# Highscores on multiple columns, efficient query, right approach

Tags: mysql, sql

Let's say we've got high scores table with columns `app_id`, `best_score`, `best_time`, `most_drops`, `longest_something` and couple more.
I'd like to collect top three results ON EACH CATEGORY grouped by app_id?

For now I'm using separate rank queries on each category in a loop:

```
SELECT app_id, best_something1,
FIND_IN_SET( best_something1, 
(SELECT GROUP_CONCAT( best_something1 
ORDER BY best_something1 DESC) 
FROM highscores )) AS rank 
FROM highscores 
ORDER BY best_something1 DESC LIMIT 3;
```

Two things worth to add:

1. All columns for specific app are being updated at the same time (can consider creating a helper table).
2. the result of prospective "turbo query" might be requested quite often - as often as updating the values.

I'm quite basic with SQL and suspect that it has many more commands that combined together could do the magic?

What I'd expect from this post is that some wise owl would at least point the direction where to go or how to go.

The sample table:
http://sqlfiddle.com/#!2/eef053/1

Here is sample result too (already in json format, sry):

> {"total_blocks":[["13","174","1"],["9","153","2"],["10","26","3"]],"total_games":[["13","15","1"],["9","12","2"],["10","2","3"]],"total_score":[["13","410","1"],["9","332","2"],["11","88","3"]],"aver_pps":[["11","4.34011","1"],["13","2.64521","2"],["12","2.60623","3"]],"aver_drop_per_game":[["11","20","1"],["10","13","2"],["9","12.75","3"]],"aver_drop_val":[["11","4.4","1"],["13","2.35632","2"],["9","2.16993","3"]],"aver_score":[["11","88","1"],["9","27.6667","2"],["13","27.3333","3"]],"best_pps":[["13","4.9527","1"],["11","4.34011","2"],["9","4.13076","3"]],"most_drops":[["11","20","1"],["9","16","2"],["13","16","2"]],"longest_drop":[["9","3","1"],["13","2","2"],["11","2","2"]],"best_drop":[["11","42","1"],["13","36","2"],["9","30","3"]],"best_score":[["11","88","1"],["13","78","2"],["9","58","3"]]}

Comment: Your issue would be much clearer to "see" if you provided sample tables (in a table format of course) and a sample of your desired output.

Comment: What is `app`? Is it another table?

Comment: http://sqlfiddle.com/

Comment: Thanks for interest, updated with more info. The output can be anything what meets the requirement mentioned. thanks

Comment: Your fiddle example has all users ids null how would one get the three "categories" for each user?

Comment: Ok, thanks, I've just updated the post once again with sample result I'd need. Already JSON. - It's a result of my looped query, but I don't thing it's the right approach. Thanks!
@JorgeCampos my bad, it's about app_id, it won't be null

Answer (score 2, accepted):

When I encounter this scenario, I prefer to employ the UNION clause, and combine the queries tailored to each ORDERing and LIMIT.

http://dev.mysql.com/doc/refman/5.1/en/union.html

UNION combines the result rows vertically (top 3 rows for 5 sort categories yields 15 rows).

For your specific purpose, you might then pivot them as sub-SELECTs, rolling them up with GROUP_CONCAT GROUPed on user so that each has the delimited list.

Comment: ! This is something ! Seem to be a really good solution. Let me test that first and confirm all other req but I loved it from the first sparkle!

Comment: I should also mention that just pivoting without using GROUP_CONCAT at all would be ideal here if your app doesn't mind getting it as a 2D result set. I will give you another answer with that approach shortly.

Comment: Oops, I meant to say without pivoting...not without GROUP_CONCAT (I confused myself)...3 dimensions of data...but outputting with users as rows directly. Am authoring the answer now.

Comment: It is easy to get confused! I just tested your solution and I think it's great- even the simplest union works for me, as long as I can rely on the order of union-ing. The next question would be, is this query server-heavy considering frequent execution on decent set of records? Is there any 'pivot point' where other solutions should be considered? Thank you! Marking as accepted!

Comment: It's the pivoting that I think will run it harder.

UNION is as efficient as running the queries in series usually, and if you've got those score fields indexed (so they're presorted), you could even make it super fast by including your app_id in the index as a covering index (see google and Percona) so that it doesn't even have to look at the table data (can grab the data right from the index).

A little sleep deprivation is keeping me from testing the other answer I want to post though, which will avoid pivoting for your purpose, I think.

Comment: Also, the true and best solution to this is to use a stored procedure to output your theoretical 3 dimensional result set as multiple 2 dimensional result sets, instead of denormalizing the data with group_concat.

With one call, you would get each category, since the stored procedure you would be calling would simply be each of the SELECTS between the BEGIN and END.

Since it's a single-shot, you'd save the latency, which I think is what you're after.

Comment: Woah, thanks for bunch of great hints! Indexes - "obvious" some would say, but I need to be told (+). Custom procedure! this is definitely something to look at in the next step. For now It's far better than I expected, since I rather sux with sql and didn't even know custom procedures can be written :) Both latency and resources - I prefer to not stress cpu. wise owls don't have a sleep depr., they hunt!

Comment: Ok, I tested what I was going to post, but it performed very poorly, even on a relatively recent version of MySQL.

If you're curious, what I did was have a sub-sub-select that returns a single-value (the 4th best score for a specific category), but has the app_ID in the WHERE criteria. I use that in the JOIN criteria to say only gather scores better than the 4th best score when joining them to the app table. There is one join for each category. (I say sub-sub-select because each of the joined tables are not the score table, but a derived table made from it that includes GROUP concat of score)

Answer (score 1):

I'd test something like this query, to see if the performance is any better or not. I think this comes pretty close to satisfying the specification:

```
 ( SELECT 99 AS seq_
        , a.category
        , CONVERT(a.val,DOUBLE) AS val
        , FIND_IN_SET(a.val,r.highest_vals) AS rank
        , a.user_id
     FROM ( SELECT 'total_blocks' AS category
                 , b.`total_blocks` AS val
                 , b.user_id
              FROM app b
             ORDER BY b.`total_blocks` DESC
             LIMIT 3
          ) a
    CROSS
     JOIN ( SELECT GROUP_CONCAT(s.val ORDER BY s.val DESC) AS highest_vals
              FROM ( SELECT t.`total_blocks` AS val
                       FROM app t
                      ORDER BY t.`total_blocks` DESC
                      LIMIT 3
                   ) s
          ) r
    ORDER BY a.val DESC
 )
 UNION ALL
 ( SELECT 97 AS seq_
        , a.category
        , CONVERT(a.val,DOUBLE) AS val
        , FIND_IN_SET(a.val,r.highest_vals) AS rank
        , a.user_id
     FROM ( SELECT 'XXX' AS category
                 , b.`XXX` AS val
                 , b.user_id
              FROM app b
             ORDER BY b.`XXX` DESC
             LIMIT 3
          ) a
    CROSS
     JOIN ( SELECT GROUP_CONCAT(s.val ORDER BY s.val DESC) AS highest_vals
              FROM ( SELECT t.`XXX` AS val
                       FROM app t
                      ORDER BY t.`XXX` DESC
                      LIMIT 3
                   ) s
          ) r
    ORDER BY a.val DESC
 )
 ORDER BY seq_ DESC, val DESC
```

To unpack this a little bit... this is essentially separate queries that are combined with `UNION ALL` set operator.

Each of the queries returns a literal value to allow for ordering. (In this case, I've given the column a rather anonymous name `seq_` (sequence)... if the specific order isn't important, then this could be removed.

Each query is also returning a literal value that tells which "category" the row is for.

Because some of the values returned are INTEGER, and others are FLOAT, I'd cast all of those values to floating point, so the datatypes of each query line up.

For the FLOAT (floating point) type values, there can be a problem with comparison. So I'd go with casting those to decimal and stringing them together into a list using `GROUP_CONCAT` (as the original query does).

Since we are returning only three rows from each query, we only need to concatenate together the three largest values. (If there's a two way "tie" for first place, we'll return rank values of `1`, `1`, `3`.)

Suitable indexes for each query will improve performance for large sets.

```
... ON app (total_blocks, user_id)
... ON app (best_pps,user_id)
... ON app (XXX,user_id)
```

Comment: Wow, this is comprehensive solution too, thank you! I like the concept of naming final output columns. Good spot on float and ints too. Will give that a go for sure. However now it's coming down to write a stored procedure, which probably would perform the best and fulfill some other 'circus requirement tasks' way easier. Once again appreciate the slice you made. It's teaching!